# Spark Range partitioning for unbalanced dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, partitioning

I have dataframe with next schema:

```
provider_id: Int,
quadkey18: String,
data: Array[ComplexObject]
```

I need to save this dataframe partitioned by provider_id and quadkey5.
In general data field quite similar in terms of size across all providers.
However some providers (certain provider_id) have data array 100x-1000x times bigger than others.

I am trying to get balance dataset with next code:

```
df
  .withColumn("qk_for_range",
    when($"provider"===high_freq_provider_id,substring($"quadkey18",1,14))
      otherwise substring($"quadkey18",1,10) )
  .withColumn("quadkey5", substring($"quadkey18",1,5) )
  .repartitionByRange(nrPartitions, $"provider", $"qk_for_range")
  .drop("qk_for_range")
  .write
  .partitionBy("provider", "quadkey5")
  .format("parquet")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .option("maxRecordsPerFile",(maxCountInPartition).toInt)
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save(exportUrl)
```

However I got really huge partition parquet files (~ 1Gb), when I want to get smaller partitions (~200 mb).
I can decrease "maxRecordsPerFile" option, but in that case I would get a lot of small files for all "light" providers (those that have small data array per record).

My question is - how to break down "fat" partitions?